# query return setof - update data

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, stored-functions

I have Postgres function, that returns setof. I can create table directly with it using `INSERT INTO`, but that is not what I want.

```
SELECT id, my_func() INSERT INTO data2
```

I need to update data in existing table based on setof result rows. How can I do this?
I need something like `SELECT id, my_func() as t UPDATE data2 SET data = t WHERE data2.id = id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us what exactly your function returns, but something like this should work:

```
update data2 
  set data = f.data_column
from my_func() as f (id, data_column)
where t.id = data2.id;
```

This assumes the function returns two columns so that you can join the target table against the function result.